# Entity Framework tries to add entity that already exists, but hasn't been updated

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

sorry but I hope someone can help!

My NewStarter Model ('Item' is just a model that contains 'ID'):

```
    public class NewStarter : Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public string PreferredName { get; set; } = "";
        public string JobTitle { get; set; } = "";
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public AppUser? LineManager { get; set; }
        public Department? Department { get; set; }
    }
```

The method to save a new 'NewStarter' item to the database:

```
        private async Task<Item> SaveItemAsync(Item item)
        {
            try
            {
                using var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
                if (item.Id == 0)
                {
                    if(item is NewStarter)
                    {
                        var newStarter = item as NewStarter;
                        context.NewStarters.Add(newStarter);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Do stuff
                }
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return item;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Now for the issue...
I have a razor page that on load, retrieves a list of a departments (Department).
I will create a new 'NewStarter' object and select (from a dropdown) the department from the departmentList

When submitting the item (SaveItemAsync), I get the following exception:
"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Departments' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

VS shows the object as I'd expect:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXsqe.png)

This is my ChangeTracker debug view, which seems to be showing as trying to add a new Department? :
[image: ChangeTracker debug view]

I'd understand if I was actively adding a department, however I've done nothing more than select the department from a list. The department object isn't being updated in any way...

I've had a google on what could be causing this, and one option seems to be to attach the item instead (context.Attach(item)), however is that just putting a plaster over something that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the debug output I could imagine that a `Department` with `Id` of -1 is the value of `Department` property of the `NewStarter` object.

If `-1` stands for no department selected, you must set the `Department` property to `null` and not to an object with `Id = -1`.

I suggest to add a property `int? DepartmentId`  to `NewStarter` as a foreign key property, in addition to the reference navigation property `Department? Department` (ref. [Relationships - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)).

I also suggest to remove the definition of `Id` in `NewStarter` since it is already defined in `Item` class.